# How to get the address of an array and save it to a register in assembly?

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips, memory-address, cpu-registers

I want to save the memory address of A[ ] in a register, say $a0 because I will pass this as an argument to a procedure even though I can reach A in any scope of the program.

In the code, the reason I used `sb` instead of `sw` is there is an allignment problem when I assemble it.

When I say `lb $a0, A` it stores `4` to `$a0`, which is the value not the address.

```
.data
    A: .space 16

.globl main
main:
    # Initialize values in the array
    addi $s0, $zero, 4
    addi $s1, $zero, 8
    addi $s2, $zero, 3
    addi $s3, $zero, 5

    # This $t0 is just used for indexing while inserting to A
    addi $t0, $zero, 0

    sb $s0, A($t0)
    addi $t0, $t0, 4
    sb $s1, A($t0)
    addi $t0, $t0, 4
    sb $s2, A($t0)
    addi $t0, $t0, 4
    sb $s3, A($t0)
    li $t0, 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use the `la` pseudo-instruction.  `la $t0, A`.**

If `A` doesn't fit in 16 bits, this will assemble to a sequence like
**`lui $t0, high16(A)` ; `ori $t0, $zero, low16(A)`**.  See [this basic MIPS instruction-set reference for LUI](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html).  Your assembler may use `addui` instead of `ori`; I think some assemblers have an option for which to choose for `li` / `la` pseudo-instructions.

There's also an `li` pseudo-instruction (for load-immediate) for use with numeric constants instead of addresses, but it works identically.

---

For the alignment problem, try making sure `A`'s address is word-aligned.  I would have thought this would happen automatically, but maybe you left out a `.asciz` string constant earlier in `.data` from the code you posted?  Anyway, either put `A` first before non-multiple-of-4 sized objects, or use a `.align` directive to pad to the next multiple of 4.

```
.data
    .align 4         # align by 4 bytes.
    A: .space 16
```

---

If `A`'s address fits in 16 bits, you don't need it or the offset in a register, just use `sb $s0, A+4($zero)` and so on.  (But if you're using sb / lb, then why still offset by 4 bytes between elements?  Why not make it a 4-byte long array of 4 bytes?)

```
.globl main
main:
    # Initialize values in the array

    li     $t0, 4
    sw     $t0, A($zero)

    addui   $t0, $zero, 8     # doing it manually without an LI pseudo-instruction
    sw     $t0, A+4($zero)

    li     $t0, 3
    sw     $t0, A+8($zero)

    li     $t0, 5
    sw     $t0, A+12($zero)

    #li    $t0, 0
```

You don't need to use a different register every time, although I guess without register-renaming [a classic-RISC pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_RISC_pipeline) might stall for a [Write-After-Read hazard (WAR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_(computer_architecture)) when `li` tried to write `t0` before the previous `sw` had read it.  On a superscalar CPU, it makes sense to mix different instruction types (ALU `addui` and memory `sw`) so they can execute in parallel instead of maybe waiting longer than necessary before the first store executes.

Also, this is arguably more human readable because the value and address go together.

Comment: I thank you for spending your time for my problem. It is very nice of you.

Comment: I am having a problem while reaching A. Say I keep the address of A in $a0, and want to reach A($a1). When I want to load that word, $a0($a1) does not work. How can I reach the elements using $a0?

Comment: @M.Kaan: MIPS has only one addressing mode: register + imm32.  If you need a 2-register address, you need a separate `addu` instruction into a temporary register.